# Reading one checkbox status and setting another checkbox dependently in javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have limited knowledge and experience with Adobe Javascript which I am using to refine some complex forms. I am copying the content of a number of questionnaire to a summary page which I will use to export data to a database. I have successfully achieved this with text and numeric fields using the following script in the destination (summary) field’s custom calculation script:

```
var v1 = getField("source_field").value;
event.value=v1
```

In the case where the destination field needs a numeric value use of +getfield(source_field) corrects the problem of generating a NaN error (Not a Number). Thanks to epascarello!!
My problem is that I need to copy checkboxes from the source questionnaires to checkboxes in the summary page. The above code(s) do not work – the destination checkbox remains unchanged. I suspect I need to read the status (off / on) of the source checkbox and set the destination checkbox accordingly. I don’t know how to construct this code which likely involves a conditional and specific checkbox setting commands. I have looked at examples on the ‘net but can’t successfully pull it together. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Can you please divide this question into points?

Comment: I think I need to do two things in the script 1. evaluate the status of one check box (source field) 2. set the status of another checkbox (destination field) conditional upon the status of the source check box

Comment: Here is what I have attempted
    var v1 = +getField("Meds.Nil").value;
    if (v1="Yes")
    (checkbox.check==true)
"Meds.Nil” is the source variable and this code is in the javascript code section of the destination checkbox variable. In the source variable under Options, output is “Yes” if the checkbox is checked.